# Pandas Dataframe - comparing values of two columns with previous rows to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to check if an event happened in the same day across multiple dates and locations. In the simplified table there is a date column, a location column and an event column. I need to make a new column called 'EVENTCHECK'. EVENTCHECK should compare the DATE in the current row with all rows above,and if it matches check the event column for 1 on the row for that date and return 1.

Below is a table of dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['DATE'] = ['2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-04','2022-01-05','2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-04','2022-01-05']
df['LOCATION'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']
df['EVENT'] = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

The correct result should be True in the EVENTCHECK column. I've tried the below, also tried using a mask but cannot figure out how to compare the current row with previous rows in the date col. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['DATE'] = ['2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-04','2022-01-05','2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-04','2022-01-05']
df['LOCATION'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']
df['EVENT'] = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]

df['EVENT_CHECK'] = (df['DATE'].isin(df['DATE'])) & (df['EVENT'] == 1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Please show expected output

Comment: And please provide a more challenging input to demonstrate a case in which there should be `False` values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are equal to all previous values, then the current value is equal to the first and no previous value was not different.

You can then use a comparison with [`groupby.transform('first')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), then a [`groupby.cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin.html):

```
df['EVENT_CHECK'] = (df['EVENT'].eq(df.groupby('LOCATION')['EVENT']
                                      .transform('first'))
                     .groupby(df['LOCATION']).cummin()
                    )
```

Same logic with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
df['EVENT_CHECK'] = (df.groupby('LOCATION', group_keys=False)
                       .apply(lambda g: g['EVENT'].eq(g['EVENT'].iloc[0])
                                         .cummin())
                     )
```

*NB. this assumes that the dates are originally sorted. If not, first add `.sort_values(by=['LOCATION', 'DATE'])` as a preliminary step.*

###### only 1 matters

If you're only interested in `1`, then you can simplify to:

```
df['EVENT_CHECK'] = df['EVENT'].eq(1).groupby(df['LOCATION']).cummin()
```

Output:

```
         DATE LOCATION  EVENT  EVENT_CHECK
0  2022-01-01        A      1         True
1  2022-01-02        A      1         True
2  2022-01-03        A      1         True
3  2022-01-04        A      1         True
4  2022-01-05        A      1         True
5  2022-01-01        B      0         True
6  2022-01-02        B      0         True
7  2022-01-03        B      0         True
8  2022-01-04        B      0         True
9  2022-01-05        B      0         True
```

##### more meaningful example:

```
         DATE LOCATION  EVENT  EVENT_CHECK
0  2022-01-01        A      1         True
1  2022-01-02        A      1         True
2  2022-01-03        A      2        False  # 2 ≠ 1
3  2022-01-04        A      1        False  # 1 not equal to all previous
4  2022-01-05        A      1        False
5  2022-01-01        B      0         True
6  2022-01-02        B      0         True
7  2022-01-03        B      0         True
8  2022-01-04        B      0         True
9  2022-01-05        B      0         True
```

##### alternative

For fun, if the dates are common to all locations, here is an alternative with reshaping and a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = df.merge(
 df.pivot(index='DATE', columns='LOCATION', values='EVENT')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.eq(d.iloc[0]).cummin())
   .stack().rename('EVENT_CHECK'),
 left_on=['DATE', 'LOCATION'], right_index=True
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in the most efficient way (vecotorized), you can do so as follows:

```
df['EVENT_CHECK'] = df.groupby('DATE')['EVENT'].transform('sum').ge(1)
```

Output (I added an additional non-event date):

```
    DATE    LOCATION    EVENT   EVENT_CHECK
0   2022-01-01  A         1     True
1   2022-01-02  A         1     True
2   2022-01-03  A         1     True
3   2022-01-04  A         1     True
4   2022-01-05  A         1     True
5   2022-01-01  B         0     True
6   2022-01-02  B         0     True
7   2022-01-03  B         0     True
8   2022-01-04  B         0     True
9   2022-01-05  B         0     True
10  2025-01-06  B         0     False
```

Comment: How do you check for different locations?

Comment: @Corralien does the location matter? My understanding was we're just looking for an event that happened on a matching date, regardless of location.

Comment: *I'm trying to check if an event happened in the same day across multiple dates and locations*

Comment: @Flint also states 'The correct result should be True in the EVENTCHECK column' for their given example, of which none of location `B` should then match if your understanding is correct. Let's see if they can clarify further

Comment: Thank you, learning a lot from this. Yes, like @Corralien states, I'm trying to find if the same event occurred at multiple locations on the same date(s).